# putting floating elements into div

Tags: html, css

I've written code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 

<style type="text/css">
* {padding: 0px;margin: 0px;}
body {width:100%}
img.logo{display:block;width:80%;margin-left:10%;margin-right:10%;}
div.down{width:80%;margin-left:10%;margin-right:10%;height:auto;border:red solid 1px;overflow: auto}
.bar{width:10%; height:100%; float:left; display:block;}
.cent{width:80%; float:left;}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<img class="logo" src="logo.gif"/>
<div class="down">
<img class="bar" src="bar.jpg"/>
<div class="cent">
//LOT OF TEXT//


</div>
<img class="bar" src="bar.jpg"/>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

And When I write lot of text into "cent" div the "down" div gets streched. However, "bar" images dont get resized despite height set (100% or inherit) which should inherit height from parent. What should I do to make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I found on the sitepoint reference for CSS height

[Site Point CSS Height Reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/height)

> The property takes a CSS length (px,
>   pt, em, etc.), a percentage, or the
>   keyword auto. Negative length values
>   are illegal.   Percentage values refer
>   to the height of the element’s
>   containing block. If the height of the
>   containing block isn’t specified
>   explicitly (that is, it depends on
>   content height), and this element
>   isn’t absolutely positioned, the
>   percentage value is treated as auto. A
>   percentage value is also treated as
>   auto for table cells, table rows, and
>   row groups.   The special auto value
>   allows the browser to calculate the
>   content height automatically, based on
>   other factors. For absolutely
>   positioned elements, for example, the
>   content height may be calculated on
>   the basis of the top and bottom
>   property values, or the top and bottom
>   margins, borders, and padding applied
>   to the element. If no hard constraints
>   are imposed by other properties, the
>   element is allowed to assume its
>   “natural” content height, on the basis
>   of the height of the content it
>   contains.

So I did as follows. HTML as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Template</title>
<link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
<img class="logo" src="logo.png"/>
<div class="down">
<img class="bar left" src="bar.jpg"/>
<div class="cent">

Lots of Text

</div>
<img class="bar right" src="bar.jpg"/>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS as follows

```
html, body, div
{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

div#container
{
width: 80%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

img.logo
{
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;

}

div.down
{
position: relative;
border: 1px solid red;
overflow: auto;
}

img.bar.left
{
display: block;
width: 10%;
height: 100%;
border: 1px solid blue;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

img.bar.right
{
display: block;
width: 10%;
height: 100%;
border: 1px solid blue;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
}

div.cent
{
width: 80%;
border: 1px solid green;
margin: 0 auto;

}
```

Now the image horizontal size change when the size o fthe content changes. Works on IE9, FF4.01, GG11, AF5 and Opera11

Answer (score 1):

You're doing this totally wrong. You should use `background-image` to achieve what you want.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
    <style type="text/css">
        .div1, .div2 {
            background: transparent url(bar.jpg) left repeat-y;
        } 
        .div2 {
            background-position: right;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="div1">
        <div class="div2">
            <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.<strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.<strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.<strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know, but I wanted to get exactly this effect.

Comment: @oneat effect would e exactly the same.

Comment: I wanted for image to strech vertically not be repeated

Comment: @oneat, generally it's bad idea to strech your images using html. if you want it wider use you graphics editor